# Login to twitter and tweet from Java (web-app)

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I want to write a simple java (or java web app) program that will allow a user to log in and post a twit. I don't even need a user interface. I can simply hard code the twit, userId, and password. I just want to know the process. I have been looking for a while now, and I have had no success so far. The following code which was finally supposed to work does not work.

The code is a simple application as opposed to a web-app. Does anyone have some code that will work with the present Twitter API? I have been trying to use twitter4j.

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;

public class TwitterUtils {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        final String consumerKey = "**********";
        final String consumerSecret = "**********";
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

        String token = requestToken.getToken();
        String tokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();
        System.out.println("My token :: " + token);
        System.out.println("My token Secret :: " + tokenSecret);

        //AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
        //twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        twitter.updateStatus("If you're reading this on Twitter, it worked!");

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//main
}//TwitterUtils
```

With the AccessToken lines commented I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/configuration.html for the detail.     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:205)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:453)
at playaround.TwitterUtils.main(TwitterUtils.java:55)
```

Java Result: 1

When I uncomment the lines, the error reads

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format. at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(AccessToken.java:50)
at playaround.TwitterUtils.main(TwitterUtils.java:53)
```

Does anyone have a complete solution I may use? Thanks.

Comment: why not just use something similar to the [Tweet button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)? it's all client-side, no need for your app to access the user's account.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` (your application's key and secret) you need `accessToken` from the user that is using your application. You get this `accessToken` from Twitter using OAuth protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Through this link ( 
http://module.minic.ro/how-to-make-a-twitter-application-tutorial/ ) you can generate consumer key,consumer secret, access token, and access token secret keys

Use this code when you get keys for Twitter object:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
.setOAuthConsumerKey("*********************")
.setOAuthConsumerSecret("******************************************")
.setOAuthAccessToken("**************************************************")
.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******************************************");
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html